# CXF: Can I refer in-memory keystore for signing?

Tags: cxf, keystore

We use CXF 3 and we use WSS4J Crypto to provide keys to sing SOAP message. I wonder is it is possible to use in-memory KeyStore to store those keys (I know it is possible to use in-memory KeyStore for SSL certificates). I know that it is possible to refer a keystore in file, but not sure if I can do it with in-memory one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not with the default "Merlin" Crypto implementation that WSS4J ships with, as this is based on a file-based Keystore. You will need to implement the Crypto interface (or extend one of the abstract classes that are in WSS4J) to support this yourself.

Colm.

Comment: Is there a way to to just use KeyStore without implementing a Crypto?